# why this program does not give error?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [int c = getchar()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119470/int-c-getchar)

```
#include <stdio.h>

   main()
   {
       int c;
       c = getchar();
       while (c != EOF) {
           putchar(c);
           c = getchar();
       }
   }
```

I dont have experience with C but i know C++ .I want to ask that **'c' here is declared as an integer type but surprisingly when i run this program , it accepts even characters** . Can anyone kindly explain .

Ref : C programming Ritchie/kernighan

Comment: In C, char type can know as integer or character :)
When use `char variable` as integer, it will print ordinary number of its character in table.
and when use as char, it will print as character

Comment: 'i know C++' -- Apparently not, since this code works identically in C++.

Answer (score 2):

> it accepts even characters

Actually, `getchar()` returns `int`, so no problem here.

Even if it returned `char`, since both `char` and `int` are integral types of the same signedness and `int` is wider than `char`, an `int` can always store a `char` using an implicit conversion (sometimes it's called an "upcast", but it's not really a cast, since it's implicit). Basically what this means is

```
int n = 'a';
```

is perfectly valid C.

Answer (score 1):

First, `getchar` returns an `int`, not `char`.

Second, `char` is widened to an `int` at assignment.