# Why does this work

Tags: c, while-loop, conditional-statements

Couldn't find a better title, so edit it if you have a better idea.

Here is while loop in C:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

How does the condition work?

How does `(c = getchar())` assignment expression "return" a value, as it is then compared to `EOF` ?

Comment: You've already got the answer. An assignment expression returns the assigned value. It is the same as `a = b = 0;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119470/int-c-getchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C an assignement operation **is** en expression whose value is the result of the assignment.

For example `a = 5` is an expression whose value is `5`.

`((c = getchar()) != EOF` calls `getchar` and puts the return value in `c` and then compares the result (now the content of `c`) = to `EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression of the *assignment* returns the **assigned** value.

When you do:

```
((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

You're comparing the assigned value  to `EOF`.

Comment: Could you turn the verbose mode on for OP's sake?  New avatar?

Answer (score 1):

In C, the assignment expression has itself the value of the assigned value.

This property allows the programmer to apply different techniques  like the one you mentioned, directly comparing the assigned value.

```
if ((a = f()) != 0) ....
```

or multiple assignments

```
a = b = f()
```