# How to read space-separated values in C?

Tags: c, file-io

I have a .txt file that I am using to learn some basic C.

Here is the txt file:

```
8
12  48  15  65  16  82  9   72
```

Here is my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(int argc, char** argv){

        char num = 0;
        //int[] arr = 0;


        if (argc != 2){
                return 0;
        }

        FILE *inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if (inputFile == NULL){
                printf("Error1\n");
                return 0;
        }

        while(!feof(inputFile)){
                num = fgetc(inputFile);
                printf("%c\n",num);
        }

        if(!feof(inputFile)){
                printf("error");
                return 0;
        }

}
```

My goal is the get an array of the second line, based on the amount of values in the first line.... essentially, we want an array with 8 values, that stores {12, 48, ....}

Comment: You can always use `sscanf`.

Comment: Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong), and `char num` should be `int num`. Blame your tutor.

Comment: Use `fscanf` with `malloc`. like [this](https://ideone.com/KKK4dd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a wrong function to read integers: in spite of returning an `int`, function `fgetc` is reading individual characters ([why `getchar` returns an `int`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7119500/335858)).

In order to read space-separated integers, use `fscanf` instead, and check the return value to decide that you have reached the end of file:

```
int n;
while (fscanf(inputFile, " %d", &n) == 1) {
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

Note that the loop above avoids using `feof` to detect the end of file condition ([why using `feof` is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/335858))

Answer (score 1):

If you aim to read a series of numbers (and nothing else), regardless of the number of line breaks in between, you could simply use `fscanf` as follows:

```
    int num;
    while(fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &num) == 1) {
            printf("%d\n",num);
    }
```

Note that `fscanf` returns the number of values successfully read in according to the format specifier, i.e. it returns `1` as long as an integral value could have been read in (and `0` otherwise).