# Why is type int needed to handle EOF and return of getchar()?

Tags: c, getchar

As written in book-

*The problem is distinguishing the end of the input from valid data. The solution is that getchar returns a distinctive value when there is no more input, a value that cannot be confused with any real character. This value is called EOF,for "end of file." We must declare c to be a type big enough to hold any value that getchar returns. We can't use char since c must be big enough to hold EOF in addition to any possible char. Therefore we use int.*

```
main()
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while(c != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand the actual reason of using int instead of char. What will be returned by EOF such that cannot be stored in char.

Comment: The text of the book you quote is clear enough. Maybe you can check on what size a char is and what size an int is and check in the manual pages what getchar returns.

Comment: other duplicates: [Why must the variable used to hold getchar's return value be declared as int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18013167/995714), [int c = getchar()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7119470/995714), [Difference between int and char in getchar/fgetc and putchar/fputc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35356322/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why must the variable used to hold getchar's return value be declared as int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013167/why-must-the-variable-used-to-hold-getchars-return-value-be-declared-as-int)

Answer (score 5):

A `char` can hold 256 different values (0 to 255). If `EOF` was a `char`, the value of `EOF` would therefore be some value between 0 and 255, which would imply that there would be *one* character that you cannot read. Therefore the value of `EOF` cannot be between 0 and 255, which implies that it cannot fit into a `char`, which implies that its type must be larger than `char`, for example an `int`.

In other words `EOF` is *not* a `char` and we don't want to store it in a `char`. It's only purpose is to enable a program to detect that one char beyond the end of the file has been attempted to read.

Or still in other words: let's suppose `EOF` is defined as 255 and therefore fit's into a `char`. Now let's suppose  `getchar` returns the value 255 (that is `EOF`). Now what does that value represent? Is it an `EOF` or is it the character 255?