# C getchar terminal problems in vs code

Tags: c

A simple program works well in vs code with digits, but it doesn't work with letters.
It seems Path is ok. At least it is ok for digits, but not ok for letters.
What might be a reason?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* copy input to output; 1st version */
int main()
{
char c;
c = getchar();
while (c != EOF) {
putchar(c);
c = getchar();
}
}
```

An error with any random letters:

```
The term 'lkj' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+ lkj <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (lkj:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: `char c;` -> `int c;` [in order to detect EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48870842/1606345)

Comment: In order to run your code from the command line you need to compile your code into a executable file (one with the extendion .exe). Apparenty you haven't a file `lkj.exe` in your current directory, hence the error message. Your C code is correct except the `char c` which should be `int c`, see previous comment.

Comment: @DavidRanieri although your comment is correcrt, this is not the actual problem here. The OP tries to run `lkj.exe` but there is no such file, hence the error message (which is an errror message from the Windows Power Shell).

Comment: @Jabberwocky Right, it was a simple comment, by the way, I see that the answer to the link I point to is yours. Very well explained.

Comment: @DavidRanieri I don't know if it was you who closed the question as dupe (which it isn't). But anyway I reopened the question.

Comment: No, it wasn't me.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Windows Power Shell.
I'm not very familiar with Power Shell, but when you type a sequence of digits, Power Shell echoes these digits (don't ask me why, but that's what's happening with my Power Shell on my Windows machine).

But when you enter a sequence of characters other than just digits, Power Shell tries to run a .exe file and if the exe file does not exist you get exactly the error message you've shown in your question.

So you're not even running your code.

Add something like `printf("This is my first C program\n");` to your code and try again. if you program runs, you should see `This is my first C program` displayed.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I compiled the program using gcc filename.c, ran the program using .\a.exe.
After that it started to work: I can type digits and letters. But I have to do it manully. Code Runner doesn't work even after all this actions.