# Opening files, reading it and count the words

Tags: c, file, count

guys! I try to make program that will find all same words in file and count it. For example my txt file: "I have a dog and I love my dOg". So my program must count word "dOg" too.

But I can't use any function except fopen, fclose, fgetc, fputc!!!

It's what I tried. My function lower must transform "dog" to normal "dog", so the program can count it. But something went wrong and it don't count anything now...

`

```
char lower(char c){

if(c>= 'A' && c<='Z')

return c+'a'-'A';

return c;

} 

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  
  char dog[] = "dog";
  int x = 0; //how many coincidence we found 
  int n = 7; // length of raw 
  int res = 0;//coincidence at all

  FILE* fin = fopen("dog.txt","r");
  if (fin == NULL) {
      puts("File in error");
      return 1;

  }

  char c; //current character 
  while (c=lower(fgetc(fin)) != EOF ){
      if (c == dog[x]){
          x++;
          if (x == n){
              res++;
              x = 0;
          }
      }
      else {
          x = 0;
      }
     
  }

  fclose(fin);

  FILE* fout = fopen("dog.txt","w");
  if (fout == NULL) {
      puts("File out error");
      return 1;
  }
  
  //printf("%i", res);
  fprintf(fout, "%i", res);
  
  fclose(fout);

  return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: ```if (c == dog[X])``` What do you think this statement does?

Comment: To begin with `c=lower(fgetc(fin)) != EOF` is wrong for two reasons. One is because [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`**. The other is because of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). You might take a closer look at your learning material and look close at what it really does.

Comment: You might also want to refresh your learning material about arrays and their sizes, and what happens if you use an index which is invalid for an array.

Comment: As some programmer dude said, you should be using an ```int``` variable to store the value of fgetc. Here's a reason why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870708/why-is-type-int-needed-to-handle-eof-and-return-of-getchar#:~:text=This%20value%20is%20called%20EOF,Therefore%20we%20use%20int.

Comment: The line ```(c = lower(fgetc(fin) != EOF)``` is doing too much at a time. You're also missing braces. Why not break the problem into two or more steps?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int compare_strings(char* first, char* sec) {
    while (*first != '\0' && *first == *sec) {
        ++first; ++sec;
    }
    return *first == *sec;
}

void lower_string(char* str) {
    while(*str) {
        if(*str >= 'A' && *str <= 'Z')
            *str = *str - ('A' - 'a');
        ++str;
    }
}

int main() {
    char word[] = "cats";
    FILE* fp = fopen("dog.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");
        return 0;
    }

    // Assuming that there will not be words longer than 255 characters (in that case you'd have to use malloc)
    int curr_word_len = 0, count = 0;
    char current_word[255] = "", c = 0; 
    
    while(c = fgetc(fp)) {
        if(c == '\n' || c == ' ' || c == ',' || c == '.' || c == EOF) { // word is finished
            current_word[curr_word_len] = '\0'; // set the terminator
            lower_string(current_word);
            if(compare_strings(current_word, word)) 
                count+=1;
            curr_word_len = 0; // reset word
        } else 
            current_word[curr_word_len++] = c;
        // as the word may be the last word in the file, we have to check for EOF here
        if(c == EOF) break;
    }
    
    printf("I've seen the word %d times", count);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Note, im not able to test this at the moment, pretty much everything is simplified as i suppose this is a school assignment, and something (Like how to make a simple print function!) is left to you, i didn't want to make everything easy! please notice me if you don't understand something