# Are both these two cleaning buffer methods equivalent?

Tags: c, while-loop, buffer, do-while, getchar

#### I was wondering:

do they do exactly the same thing? calling `c = getchar` on expression is the same as doing it with a `do...while` loop?

```c
void clrbuf(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

```c
void clrbuf(void)
{
    int c;
    do c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

edit: c was once typed `char`, but folks told me `int` was the appropriate type for it

Comment: Both better as `int c;` to distinguish and cope with the typical 257 different responses from `getchar()`.

Comment: Well, not only better, it is a must

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119470/int-c-getchar

Comment: C or C++? These are two different languages.

Comment: C++: `stream_name.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: Both are wrong.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen C. I didn't know it could be different in C++. I'll delete the tag. thanks

Comment: why, @0___________?

Comment: `c` has wrong type.

Comment: would simply `int c` instead of `char c` make it better, then?

Comment: Also: `while (1) { int c = getchar(); if (c == '\n' || c == EOF) return; } } `

Answer (score 3):

For starters the variable `c` should be declared like

```
int c;
```

because if the type `char` behaves as the type `unsigned char` then this condition

```
c != EOF
```

will be always true.

According to the C Standard (7.21 Input/output <stdio.h>)

**EOF**

> **which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and a negative value**, that is returned by several functions to indicate
> end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream;

So if the type `char` behaves as the type `unsigned char` (this depends on compiler options) then the value stored in the variable `c` after the integer promotion to the type `int` will be still a non-negative value.

The first while loop

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

may be rewritten using the comma operator like

```
while ( c = getchar(), c != '\n' && c != EOF );
```

that is in fact it consists of two parts: the assignment expression `c = getchar()` and the condition `c != '\n' && c != EOF`.

As you can see it is equivalent to the do-while statement

```
do c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

However the first while loop

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

is more expressive and clear.

Comment: The first loop is more idiomatic C (and that helps make it more expressive and clear).